# Woo Themes - Canvas Theme - Mobile VIew Navigation Menu

Tags: wordpress, canvas, mobile, woothemes

Changing of the Text of the Navigation Menu for Mobile Viewers..

In old version of canvas theme. For mobile view I have successfully changed the text of Navigation bar and wrote the site name there. This helped us to take out ads and contents to above fold.

[image: See the Text of Navigation Menu]

But in the new version of canvas (Canvas 5.3.0 and Framework 5.5.5) I am not able to figure out where to change it. Could you guide us a bit and tell us exactly where we could change the Text of the Navigation menu.

[image: New Version Canvas Theme - Navigation]